# Can not see "Manage" button in Scheduled Jobs

Tags: scheduled-apex, cron

I have System Administrator Profile. The “View Setup and Configuration” checkbox is checked. When my CRON expression is like (monthly):

```
'0 0 3 * * ?';
```

I can see the "Manage" button, but when my CRON expression is like (weekly):

```
'0 0 3 ? * *';
```

I can not see the button. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second job example is not weekly, that's daily. To specify a weekly schedule, select at least one day:

```
'0 0 3 ? * WED';
```

Note that only weekly and monthly jobs are supported by the UI, so if your cron string specifies * for the fifth and sixth parameter, it will not be supported in the UI, and you will not see a Manage option.

Comment: @DmitriyYurkin You're welcome!